# Задание по учету сотрудников компании, через Array list

Tags: java, коллекции

Не могу разобраться с пунктом 3, как мне реализовать данный метод?
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[![3][main]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW35L.png)

[image: Employee]

Comment: в main напишите не searchBusurname, а Employee.searchBusurname().

Answer (score 1):

Я предпочитаю функциональное решение:

```java
public static int searchBySurname(String surname, String name, List<Employee> employeeList) {
    return IntStream.range(0, employeeList.size())
        .filter(i -> employeeList.get(i).surname.equals(surname) 
                  && employeeList.get(i).name.equals(name)
        )
        .findAny().orElse(-1);
}
```

Если с этим трудности, то можно старым добрым способом:

```java
public static int searchBySurname(String surname, String name, List<Employee> employeeList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++) {
        Employee employee = employeeList.get(i);
        if (employee.surname.equals(surname) && employee.name.equals(name)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```